# How to find out the STL version

Tags: c++, stl

I've been asked to provide someone with the version of STL I'm using. Unfortunately I don't know how to get this, and haven't been able to find anything on the web!

I'm working on Ubuntu, if that makes a difference, gcc 4.8.4.

Comment: Basically, the information the person is asking for would be something like "Ubuntu, gcc 4.8.4" and then a note about whether you're calling -std=c++11, -std=c++14, etc. when you compile.

Comment: The STL isn't really distributed with C++. You get the standard library, and there isn't really a version number for that. There are different standards which the language and library must conform to (e.g. C++03, C++11, C++14.) So the question doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, There is no such thing called STL version. There are different C++ versions and compiler versions supporting these C++ versions.

For example, on Linux, You link your program to **libstdc++.so** (which includes the STL implementation) in general and this shared library changes with g++ version.

On Linux however, If you really want to know the version of libstdc++ you can try to use `readelf` and parse the output (which is not a really a good way).

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but google directed me straight here. I had the same problem as OP to find out which STL version is supported by a C++ compiler I use.

Essentially, [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/) has a section on [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support). The table says which compilers support C++X etc.; in my case, I am interested in GCC. I work on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS that currently ships GCC 7.3.0 from January 15, 2018, at the time of writing it.

Essentially, I checked compiler version, e.g.:

```sh
user-home$ g++ -v
[...]
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)
```

and then the table states GCC 7.3.0 supports C++17 (with plenty of details on which features are exactly supported).

PS. There are also links to particular compiler releases, again in my case [GCC](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/releases.html), and particular versions, such as [GCC 7.3.0](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/gcc-7/).

Answer (score 0):

There's no common STL version define, but a number for each __cpp_lib feature.

See your `<version>` header and
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/feature_test

e.g.

```
#if defined(__cpp_lib_list_remove_return_type) && \
    __cpp_lib_list_remove_return_type >= 201806
```